# Deploy built war in server using jenkins

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, I configured Jenkins with  my CVS and I am stuck, after building the project using Jenkins I need it to be deployed automatically into the server so I can access the project.

Comment: how and where should I configure it as it will automatically be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by adding a "post-build" action in Jenkins, action of type can be "Deploy war/ear to a container" - that let's you define your configuration. Your question is too broad. I would suggest you read up on jenkin configurations or at least tinker with it.

Comment: I missed to install the deploy plugin that was the reason "Deploy war/ear to a container" was not found. Thanks for the third eye